# gotoandstop problems actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a memory game program and when the timer runs out, I want it to go to frame 3 where it displays the "game failed" page.

I have it all set up, except when the game runs out of time, the frame just appears to overlap the original frame, instead of going to a completely separate page.

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class MemoryGame extends MovieClip{

    private var firstTile:cards;
    private var secondTile:cards;
    private var pauseTimer:Timer;
    private var score:int;
    private var cardCount:int;
    var seconds:Number;
    var minutes:Number;


    var numberDeck:Array = new Array(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6);


    public function MemoryGame(){

        //TIMER FUNCTION
        var levelTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 180);
        levelTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);
        levelTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);

        // LEVEL FUNCTION
        easyBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, easyButtonClicked);
        medBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, medButtonClicked);
        hardBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hardButtonClicked);

        score = 0;
        txtScore.text=""+score;

        //Level button events
        function easyButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
            removeChild(levelText);
            trace("easy button clicked!");
            seconds = 0;
            minutes = 1;
            txtTime.text = "1:00";
            levelTimer.start();
            setupTiles();
        }

        function medButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
            removeChild(levelText);
            trace("medium button clicked!");
            seconds = 30;
            minutes = 0;
            txtTime.text = "0:30";
            levelTimer.start();
            setupTiles();
        }

        function hardButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
            removeChild(levelText);
            trace("hard button clicked!");
            seconds = 15;
            minutes = 0;
            txtTime.text = "0:15";
            levelTimer.start();
            setupTiles();
        }


        //Timer handlers
        function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void {
            if (seconds > 00) {
            seconds -=1;
            }

            else {
                if (minutes > 0) {minutes -=1;seconds = 59;}
        }
                txtTime.text = minutes+":"+(seconds >= 10 ? seconds : "0"+seconds);
            }

        function timerCompleteHandler(e:TimerEvent):void {
            e.target.reset();
            e.target.stop();
            trace("game over!");
        }



        //Tiles set up
        function setupTiles(){
        for(x=1; x<=4; x++) {
            for (y=1; y<=3; y++){
                var randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random()*numberDeck.length);
                var tile:cards = new cards();
                tile.card = numberDeck[randomCard];
                numberDeck.splice(randomCard,1);
                tile.gotoAndStop(9);
                tile.x = (x-1) * 150;
                tile.y = (y-1) * 200;
                tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,tileClicked);
                addChild(tile);
                cardCount = cardCount + 1
            }
        }
    }
    }




    public function tileClicked(event:MouseEvent) {
        var clicked:cards = (event.currentTarget as cards);
        if (firstTile == null){
            firstTile = clicked;
            firstTile.gotoAndStop(clicked.card);
        }
        else if (secondTile == null && firstTile != clicked){
            secondTile = clicked;
            secondTile.gotoAndStop(clicked.card);
            if (firstTile.card == secondTile.card){
                pauseTimer = new Timer(1000, 1);
                pauseTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,removeCards);
                pauseTimer.start();

            }
            else {
                pauseTimer = new Timer(1000, 1);
                pauseTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,resetCards);
                pauseTimer.start();
            }
        }

        if (seconds == 0){
            this.gotoAndStop(2);
            pauseTimer.stop();
            //levelTimer.stop();
        }
    }


    public function resetCards(event:TimerEvent) {
        firstTile.gotoAndStop(9);
        secondTile.gotoAndStop(9);
        firstTile = null;
        secondTile = null;
        pauseTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,resetCards);
        score = score - 2;
        txtScore.text=""+score;
    }


    public function removeCards(event:TimerEvent){
        removeChild(firstTile);
        removeChild(secondTile);
        firstTile = null;
        secondTile = null;
        pauseTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,removeCards);
        score = score + 10;
        txtScore.text=""+score;
        cardCount = cardCount - 2;
        trace("Cardcount: " + cardCount);

        if (cardCount == 0){
            this.gotoAndStop(2);
            txtFinalScore.text=" "+score;
            pauseTimer.stop();          
            }
                }
}   
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an object using addChild(object) it isn't associated with keyframes along the timeline.

So what you need to do is rather than jumping to frame 2, removeChild(object) or object.visible = false all children you don't want and addChild(object) your 'out of time' assets.

A good work ethic is to create destroy() functions that remove and null any unwanted assets. This way you can easily remove unwanted items and free up memory.

Comment: Okay got it working! Now how would I go about resetting the game when I click the "replay" button? Just add all the children and go back a frame?

Comment: I would suggest to try forgetting about jumping to frames. Try to set your code up with functions that do certain tasks, e.g. setup a new game, end a game, start next level etc.